# In outlook add-ins set cookie and get cookie not work

Tags: google-chrome, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In outlook web add-ins cookies not work , when i set the cookie inside the taskpane code , it is not set in cookies section but localStorage works without any issue

when I open new modal using "office.displacyAsync" from that taskpane able to set the cookie inside the modal but close that modal cookie cleared

Inside the taskpane set the cookie is not work , it is not set and get also return null

Any domain issue ?

Any thoughts about this please share me

Note :  Outlook Add-ins -  react-framework outlook add-ins

Comment: There are several aspects that should be clarified - 1. It would be great to see the code used. 2. What is your host application and version?

Comment: Thanks for Your reply, Now it is work , I have hosted my app in local ,In cookie set i missed to add the "sameSite=none" , so it is not work , add-ins run on under the outlook add-ins host but it is not take cookies , after that key word add , it is works , once again thanks for take time to reply my question

Comment: Great news! Thank you for sharing the solution for others.